# Android Studio: fails whenever trying to start application a second time

Tags: android, android-studio

Having an issue with Android Studio:
I can run my android app the first time I hit "Run" (i.e. the green triangle). It will then start the AVD and load my application so I can test and debug it.
But whenever I want to start the application again (i.e. typically after having done some modification) then the gradle build invariably end in:

```
   ...
   (!) Run Task
Android issues: 1 Error
   (!) Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
```

The right hand side pane reads:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord$Op, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

Why is this not loading and restarting the new/modified version of the application. I located misc. threads that posed the same question but none of the advice given there helped me fix this. So I still always need to kill the AVD and restart it which is most tedious and time-consuming because it then always first needs to reboot! How can I fix this?

My application's gradle file reads:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.application.mmo.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

What am I missing? Why is this not working and replacing the installed app with the new version?

PS.: I won't claim that the previous Eclipse-based Android development environment was perfect. It was definitely far from that! But with that IntelliJ-based environment I have far more troubles and weirdoes! If things don't work here I always find it extremely difficult and time-consuming to figure out why something doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `build.gradle` does not have any `com.android.support:support-v4` (except possibly inside the `libs` directory, where it better should be deleted) and therefore I'd assume, that it had been edited until it does not match the error message anymore...

run `./gradlew :app:dependencies > ./dependencies.txt` in the terminal to see what depends on `support-v4` and then use `exclude` to make sure, that each library only exists **once** within a build configuration.

in order to debug, it's not this button: [image: run], but this button: [image: debug].

Comment: Nope - I haven't edited anything in that file. It's what Android studio generated. I don't know gradle well enough, yet, to dare changing anything. It's still a book with seven seals for me. Thus - pardon my ignorance - but where exactly would I need to add this "com.android.support:support-v4" you mention or "use exclude"?

Comment: @mmo most likely you just have to delete your duplicate `support-v4` library from the `libs` directory, which may be a relic from the `ant` build... and I did not tell to add it anywhere, read closely.

Comment: @mmo just explained it in another answer (another class, the same produce): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695425/549372

Comment: Thanks! Indeed there was this android-support-v4.jar (or similar, don't recall the exact name) in the libs folder. That's where I had to add it when still developing under Eclipse. Deleted that and then things got better...