# Project fails rebuild but APK compiles and runs correctly

Tags: android

Here are the errors I get when I run "Rebuild Project"

```
Program type already present: org.apache.commons.net.DatagramSocketClient Message
{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.commons.net.DatagramSocketClient, 
sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: 
Error while merging dex archives: 
C:\Users\Dave\Studio Projects\sbandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19, 
C:\Users\Dave\Studio Projects\sbandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, 
C:\Users\Dave\Studio Projects\sbandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, 
C:\Users\Dave\Studio Projects\sbandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, 
C:\Users\Dave\Studio Projects\sbandroid\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar
```

As the title indicates, if I simply press Run or Debug in Studio, the APK comes together fine and no errors are flagged during the gradle build.

Should I be concerned about this build behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the complaint reads ...

```
Program type already present: org.apache.commons.net.DatagramSocketClient
```

which I've answered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685122/using-firestore-later-than-15-0-0-version-is-causing-an-error/51695425#51695425) recently - and it is adoptable, because the problem is almost "the same". you'd just have to find **any duplicate** `org.apache.commons` dependencies and then exclude them from the build (one of them has to stay left).

Comment: You were correct: taking out one of the dependencies allowed the build to work as expected.
Enjoy your day.