# Resolve duplicate classes with firebase and dialog-flow

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dialogflow-es

I am working on a mobile app where I need dialog-flow in order to get some information from a user message. The problem is, when I implement dialog-flow into the app gradle, I get an error on build, saying that I have multiple duplicate classes ( conflicting with firebase classes).

I've tried methods suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695425/11023871

and even searched on the github repository of dialog-flow:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/5608#issue-462434090

I tried to exclude 'google-protobuf', but that didn't help (I got compilation error on dialog-flow components).

I attached my dependencies below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.99.0-alpha'
}
```

**EDIT**
These are some of the duplicates specified by gradle:
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Duplicate class com.google.api.AnnotationsProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the duplicate classes and it's jars, but I never excluded something from gradle. Could you please help me out? For example, I have this: "Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)"

I'm not sure why these jars are duplicating the same classes or which one you want to keep. But you can do something like

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    ... 

} 
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'protolite-well-known-types')
```

Comment: I did the same thing yesterday, but then it crashed my firebase configuration. I will try another way around. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck with the same issue and after months of debugging and thanks to an update from Google and Firebase, I came by a solution that's working.
I needed to change library versions of Firebase and dialog flow.
Change min SDK version to 19 if lesser than 19 in your project.

Firebase implementation:
[image: Firebase implementation]

Dialog flow implementation:
[image: Dialog flow implementation]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following snippet to your `build.gradle` and then run `gradle findDuplicates`. This will list any duplicate classes and which jars they are in. After that you can see which ones you want to exclude.

```
task findDuplicates {
   doLast {
      Map<String, List<File>> pathMap = [:] 
      configurations.runtime.each { file ->
         FileTree tree = file.directory ? fileTree(file) : zipTree(file) 
         tree.visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
            if (!fvd.directory) {
               String path = fvd.path
               List<File> fileList = pathMap[path]?:[] 
               fileList << fvd.file
               pathMap[path] = fileList
            } 
         } 
      } 
      pathMap.each { path, fileList ->
         if (fileList.size() > 1) {
            println "Found duplicate $path in $fileList" 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Gradle fails to complete task with message:
Execution failed for task ':app:findDuplicates'.
> Could not get unknown property 'runtime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

Comment: Replace `configurations.runtime.each` with `configurations.implementation.each` or maybe `configurations.androidTestImplementation.each`. I'm not an android user, but I know gradle

Comment: Well, I have the duplicate classes and it's jars, but I never excluded something from gradle. Could you please help me out?
For example, I have this:
"Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.16.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.16.0)"