# Duplicate Class found while adding Google Photos API Dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, google-photos-api

Throwing Duplicate Class found error after adding the google photos library api dependency

> 'com.google.photos.library:google-photos-library-client:1.5.0'

. Tried almost every solution present in SO, but nothing works.

My Gradle (Module) File (Dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
//    implementation project(':gcm')


    //design
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:${design_version.design}"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:${design_version.card_view}"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:${design_version.recycler_view}"
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${design_version.constant_layout}"
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    //image view
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //facebook integration
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.37.0'

    //image cropper
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'

    //chart
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

    //retrofit & square ok http & gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.1"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:19.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:19.3.1'

    //validator
    implementation 'com.github.SoumikBhatt.toaster:validator:1.2.6'
    //popup
    implementation 'com.github.SoumikBhatt.toaster:custompopup:1.2.6'
    //proToast
    implementation 'com.github.SoumikBhatt:ToastLikeAPro:1.0.1'
    //Utils
    implementation 'com.github.SoumikBhatt:Utills:1.0.1'
    //force update
    implementation 'com.github.SoumikBhatt:PushNotification:1.1.5'

    //lottie
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    //spotlight
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:spotlight:2.0.1'

    //google photos
    implementation 'com.google.photos.library:google-photos-library-client:1.5.0'

    //flurry
//    api 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Full error :

```
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-1.17.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.17.0) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules jetified-proto-google-common-protos-1.17.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.17.0) and jetified-protolite-well-known-types-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:17.0.0)
.
.
.

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Probably a transitive dependency - where another lib depends on `google-photos` and is thus included in there. Any ideas which it may be, because there's dozens of libs here

Comment: May be the firebase and google play dependencies are causing trouble

Comment: Yeah that must be it. Just find and `exclude` the troublesome dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate! I solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like Firebase has a similar dependency. Try suppressing in one of the dependencies in your `gradle`

Like this underneath the dependency:

```
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'protolite-well-known-types')
```

It should be something similar like this.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56937743/13826785)

Comment: After adding that `Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules` error appears

Comment: You may need to find all the duplicate dependencies and add this line to the other ones changing for each duplicate.

Comment: I did that but it stops my firebase services. And I found out that `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.7'` this is causing all the trouble. Removed this and it works well. Thanks for your help. Accepting your answer.