# i tried connecting android project with firebase which was generating error

Tags: java, android, firebase

I tried to resolve it but the  problem is that we are using google dialogflow in our app

So on adding  firebase Firestore dependency it is having duplicate classes in both .
I tried to remove duplicate classes and also searched for solution on stack Overflow but nothing worked.

Solution referred (unsuccessful) [Resolve duplicate classes with firebase and dialog-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922949/resolve-duplicate-classes-with-firebase-and-dialog-flow)

i tried removing jcenter from the build.gradel but it doesn't work because it was used in the android project

iam sharing my aap level gradel file and project level gradel file

plz help

App level build.gradel

```
   plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cureya_chatbot"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module'

    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.30.0'
    // youtube video player.

        implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'


    // circular imageview
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    //progress bar

    implementation 'com.sasank.roundedhorizontalprogress:roundedhorizontalprogress:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.eyalbira.loadingdots:loading-dots:1.0.2'
   // compile 'com.github.glomadrian:loadingballs:1.1@aar'
}
```

```
project level build.gradel

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        /* maven {
             url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
         }*/

        mavenCentral()

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGMty.png)

Comment: Could you please add more details about the error? Error messages and stack traces are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the firebase classpath in the build.gradle.

1. Open Your project
2. Chose tools from the status bar
3. Select firebase from the dialog
4. Now Connect to the firebase.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the Firebase or Firestore dependencies to your project.

1. Open the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Create a new project
3. Add an Android app to your Firebase project - there is a step for step tutorial on Firebase

Easy to understand tutorial by Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=en