# Adding Pub/Sub with Firestore causes duplicate class errors

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, dependencies, google-cloud-pubsub

Adding Pub/Sub library with Firestore causes duplicate class issues. Firestore without Pub/Sub working perfectly fine with the required functionality. I don't want to exclude anything from Firestore and Pub/Sub dependencies to fix conflicts as both have some kind of implementation conflict so as per my understanding nothing to exclude from both libraries to work properly with their dependencies. Please help me to fix this issue.

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "com.google.protobuf"


android {
    namespace 'com.example.lottieanimation'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lottieanimation"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libc++_shared.so'
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    //implementation project(path: ':PubSubSync')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.16.0'

    implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub:1.123.7') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
}
```

**Errors:** There is a big list of duplicate class errors, just mentioning a few. You can recreate it on your end.

> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AnnotationsProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProvider$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProviderOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirement$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthRequirementOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Authentication$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthenticationRule$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.14.3 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.14.3) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known issue with two workarounds currently available to try out:

1. Exclude the `protolite-well-known-types` dependency from the Firebase libraries in your build configuration. There is an example for how to do this in a thread with a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922949/resolve-duplicate-classes-with-firebase-and-dialog-flow).
2. Try updating the Firestore SDK version you are using (or downgrading it). This would involve trying to match the versions of the `proto-well-known-types` from the pubsub libraries and the Firestore SDK to match up and eliminate the duplicate class conflict. Alternatively you could also try adjusting the version of the pub sub libraries you are using.

Also please [see this closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3109) that discusses a very similar issue and workaround as 1.